# Counting number of occurrences of person

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a formula that can help me automate the counting of lateness occurrences in a data sheet.

For example I have 20 staffs and all their lateness data is pulled together. My criteria is to count how many time alex was late within the month.

I tried using the countif functions in excel but was not able to generate the outcome I intend.

Answer (score -1):

I assume following:

1. Employee names are in Column 1 & their arrival time in office for
   the month is recorded from column B2 to Z2.

   2. Count for late coming for this range is recorded in cell AA2 for an employee.
   3. This range is format to Time (e.g. 13:10)
   4. An employee is marked late if his / her arrival time is beyond 10:10.

Try this function in cell AA2

```
=countif(B2:Z2,">10:10")
```